# can't mix order by and group by in sql

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, ms-access-2007

I got a problem with sql. i dunno why access and sql server keep show me the error. 
I use phpmyadmin, but no issue.

I have 1 table. My table name is t_data

```
ID  MasterCode  DetailCode  Description  Item  Status
1       1           1.1      Resources   Meat     1
2       1           1.1      Resources   Meat     1
3       1           1.1      Resources   Meat     1
4       1           1.1      Resources   Meat     1
5       3           3.1       Utility    oil      1
6       2           2.1      Transport   BBM      1
```

I want to query that table and want the result looks like:

```
MasterCode  Description
    1       Resources
    2       Utility
    3       Transport
```

And here is my sql syntax

```
"select MasterCode, Description from t_data group by Description order by MasterCode"
```

Usually i just use that sql syntax, and i can get what i want. But now i can't.

> you tried to execute a query which does not include the specified expression as an aggregate function.

I got that error if i'm using access and sql server. If i'm using phpmyadmin in XAMPP, it working fine. But I don't want to use phpmyadmin. I want to use access or sql server.

I already search on google about that error. and i change my sql into this.

```
"select count(*), Description from t_data group by Description "
```

and`"select a.categoryMaster, b.categoryDesc from t_category a inner join t_category b on a.categoryDetail = b.categoryDetail"`

not solved my problem, because i want to get the MasterCode too.

any solution? thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `DISTINCT`:

```
select distinct MasterCode, Description 
from t_data
order by MasterCode;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a28a1/4)

Or you might be able to use an aggregate function like `MAX()`:

```
select max(MasterCode) MasterCode, Description 
from t_data
group by Description
order by MasterCode;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a28a1/8)

Comment: I like distinct, but otherwise, why not `SELECT t_data.mastercode, t_data.description
FROM t_data
GROUP BY t_data.mastercode, t_data.description` ?

Comment: @Remou I initially went with `DISTINCT`, by the time I was going to add the `GROUP BY` answer it was already posted so I didn't want to duplicate it. :)

Comment: Remou - i already do like what you said before i post this question. but i got an error. :)
@bluefeet - thanks for your answer. its correct.. but the second its give me an error. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT MasterCode, Description 
FROM t_data 
GROUP BY Description, MasterCode 
ORDER BY MasterCode
```

Comment: hi.. thanks for your answer. its give me correct input.. but bluefeet come first.. i just vote +1. thanks. :)

Comment: Happy to see that it helped you! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select min(MasterCode) MasterCode, Description 
from t_data 
group by Description 
order by MasterCode
```

OR

```
select MasterCode, Description 
from t_data 
group by MasterCode,Description 
order by MasterCode
```

Comment: Hi.. thanks for your answer.. the first one is correct.. but the second, i hit an error.. bluefeet come first with the correct answer.. i just give vote +1 to yours. thanks. :)

Comment: I got this error. "Circular reference caused by alias 'MasterCode' in query definition's SELECT list...

Comment: you just check the above answer by Anil Soman.Its the same query.

Comment: sorry.. wrong typing.. the second one is correct.. the first one is wrong.

Comment: pls check now.that was in sql server i used as keyword.but in mysql its not required

Comment: okay.. i can run it already. thanks for your patient to teach me n guid me. i vote your comment. thanks AnandPhadke. :)